# Restrict view access

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a project that make use of ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET Web API. Basically, pure javascript Ajax call is used to access Web API (instead of MVC Controller) in separate project. The return current user id and role is saved as session using sessionStorage.setItem (not HttpContext.Current.Session). And the entire point of the controller inside MVC is for returning view only.

The challenge i am facing is to redirect the user to 404 page without flickering should the user is not authenticated for the view. Currently, sessionStorage.getItem is used in determining whether the user is authenticated in a particular cshtml file. Since it is a javascript solution, it does flicker and shows the page before being redirect to 404.

I know that MVC 5 itself do come with authorization attribute for controller, but it seems that it is not applicable in this situation. Furthermore, the structure of this project is basically fixed and I am not allow to change sessionStorage.setItem to HttpContext.Current.Session.

Given the restriction above, I seems not be able to found out a solution to this.

Note: The final outcome is to return 404 page before the page being rendered if the user is not authenticated. Hope someone can help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `Attributes`

```
public class CheckSession : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {



                //if cookie does not exist, redirect to 404 in error controller
                if(!HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("myCookie"))
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary() { { "controller", "Error" }, { "action", "Some404view" } });

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);


        }

    }
```

And then decorate your action with

```
[CheckSession()]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
}
```

Comment: as I have mentioned in my post, the session is set using sessionStorage.setItem, and you can't use HttpContext.Current.Session to get item set by sessionStorage. One is client side storage and another is server side storage.

Comment: my bad then. Browser  Session storage  can't be accessed on the server side. You will have to create a cookie. Cookie is transmitted, and you can access it on the server side.

I have modified my response for a cookie check, as a suggestion and answer to your problem.